# Perl - can't open file with Win32::OLE

Tags: perl

I'm trying to open a `.docx` file using the following code:

```
require Win32::OLE;
my $docfile = "C:/Users/me/Documents/file.docx";
my $Word = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Word.Application');
unless ($Word) { $Word = Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application', sub {$_[0]->Quit;}) or die "oops\n"; }
$Word->{visible} = 1;
my $File = $Word->Documents->Open($docfile);
$File->PrintOut();
$File->Close(); 
$Word->Quit();
```

But i get the following error:

> OLE exception from "Microsoft Word":
>
> Sorry, we couldn’t find your file. Is it possible it was moved,
>   renamed or deleted?  (C://Users/me/Documents/...)

How can i fix this? Why does it add // to my path?
(needless to say, the file does exist in the system and that is the correct path).

Thanks!

Comment: I've never worked with Win32::OLE so this is a guess. Maybe it wants backslashes in the path?

Comment: But be aware - you might need to escape them if you're double quoting.

Comment: Which version of Word is this? I do not have the most recent version, but maybe it's trying to treat it as a UNC or something. In any case, what happens if you just use `my $docfile = join '\\', qw(C: Users me Documents file.docx);`? Also, `use Win32::OLE; $Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;`

Comment: Not everything on Windows will accept a `/` as a directory separator. You might have to write that as `my $docfile = 'C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\file.docx';` The double slashes are necessary because ``\`` is the escape character. There's also the obvious question... are you *really sure* `C:\Users\me\Documents\file.docx` exists and is readable? Check it in the code with a `-r $docfile`.

Comment: @Schwern Yes i'm sure, and unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use `canonpath` from `File::Spec::Function` to normalise the file path and change the path separators to backslashes

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Win32::OLE;
use File::Spec::Functions 'canonpath';

my $docfile = "C:/Users/me/Documents/file.docx";
my $word    = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Word.Application') or die;

$word->{visible} = 1;

my $file = $word->Documents->Open(canonpath($docfile)) or die;
$file->PrintOut;
$file->Close; 

$word->Quit;
```

Comment: With this solution, how can i print out to the console the contents of the file? (as text)

Comment: You can only do with `Win32::OLE` things that you could do manually with the Word application. You can't display plain text from Word, so you can't do it this way either.

Comment: Ok.. so how could i do it then? Should i create a new post?

Comment: You could use Perl and `Win32::OLE` to **Save as...** your document to a text file, and then read and print that file in the same program. I've closed your question as being a duplicate of another that has an alternative solution. If you need more help then, yes, ask another question.